# Requesting at least one of two fields in a Form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I've done a model which has the `email` and `phone` fields and I want to make only one of both obligatory. In other words, you only need to complete one of them in order to send the form.

I've tried to do this:

```
class ClientQueriesModel(models.Model):
    # [...]
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class ClientQueriesModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientQueriesModel
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'subject', 'message']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ClientQueriesModelForm, self).clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("email")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("phone")
        if not cc_myself and not subject:
            raise forms.ValidationError("At least one of both field must be completed: email or phone number.")
```

But it doesn't work. The form isn't sent, but the user doesn't see any error message, the page just refreshes (without sending it but cleaning the `name` field).

**How can I make from two fields one obligatory?**

Note that I'm using a custom Form template, so if I must perform any edit in my HTML template (which, I haven't found on the internet), please tell me.

**P.S:** I'm using Django 1.11.

**Edit:**

This is my `view`:

```
def about(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientQueriesModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            register = form.save()
            return base(request, 'about', make_form=False)
    else:
        form = ClientQueriesModelForm()
    return base(request, 'about', form=form, make_form=True)
```

`base` is a function that I use to call Django's `render` with some additional arguments:

```
def base(request, file, **kargs):        
    return render(request, f"vistaprevia/{file}.html", {"background_images": BACKGROUND_IMAGES, 'background_image': choice(BACKGROUND_IMAGES), **kargs})
```

My form template is:

```
<form action="/about" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }} <!--I found this on the internet, not exactly sure what it does-->
    <table class="query">
      <thead>
          <th>Parametro</th>
          <th>Datos</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!--[...]-->
        <tr>
          <th>{{form.email.label_tag}}</th>
          <th>{{form.email.errors}}{{form.email}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>{{form.phone.label_tag}}</th>
          <th>{{form.phone.errors}}{{form.phone}}</th>
        </tr>
        <!--[...]-->
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
          <tr><th colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></th></tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: This is correct and should work. Can you show the view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, done

Comment: `if not cc_myself and not subject:` make both fields mandatory, should be: `if not cc_myself or not subject:` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `form.non_field_errors` is a list, I think you should iterate through that list and display the errors.

```
{% for err in form.non_field_errors %}
     {{err}}
{% endfor %}
```

Also, you said `at least one field` should be mandatory, but you have:

```
if not cc_myself and not subject
```

Which make both fields mandatory. Replace `and` with `or`.

Comment: Thanks. But `not cc_myself or not subject` sadly doesn't work (I don't know why). Instead `not (cc_myelf != None or subject != None)` works